# Question concerning cross product and orthonormal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal, orthogonality

Assume we have a vector $u= (u_1.u_2, u_3) \in R^3$

My problem is to find vectors $\vec w, \vec v$ such that $u= v \times w$
All vectors should be orthonormal.

If $u= (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ ,is there a way to express these vectors $\vec w, \vec v$ with respect to $\vec u$.

If there is, I would like to see an example.

I am supposed to build a matrix whose columns consist of $A =(\vec v, \vec w, \vec u)$ 
Remember that all vectors should be orthonormal to each other, and that $u= v \times w$

This matrix A will represent a rotation matrix, an element $\in SO(3)$

My goal is to show that $R= ASA^T$ (S a general rotation matrix around z-axis) is again a an element $\in SO(3)$, a rotation around the unit axis $u$,  on the the form as you see in this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

Comment: I updated my answer below, but you can actually show your goal without looking at matrix columns or entries, and just using the characterization of matrices $B \in SO(3)$ as those for which ${}^t B B = 1$ and $\det B > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any vector $v$ orthonormal to $u$; one way to do this is to pick any vector $v'$ not parallel to $u$ and then apply the [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to the pair $(u, v')$. Then, set $w := u \times v$, so that $(u, v, w)$ is an oriented orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$; in particular, $(v, w, u)$ is also an oriented orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and so $$u = v \times w$$ as desired. (If one isn't familiar with this characterization of such bases, we can alternately see this with the iterated cross product identity
$$a \times (b \times c) = b \cdot (a \times c) - c \cdot (a \times b).\text{)}$$

One can show your desired result (that $R \in SO(3)$) quickly using the characterization of matrices $B \in SO(3)$ as exactly those for which ${}^t B B = I$ and $\det B > 0$.

Comment: But OP also wants orthonormality (not just orthogonality).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that before---that makes the argument easier, and I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $u_1=0$, let $v=(1,0,0)$ and let $w=u\times v$.

If $u_2=0$, let $v=(0,1,0)$, etc.

Otherwise, let $v=(u_2,-u_1,0)/\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}$, etc.

Comment: So if we have that $u=(u_1, u_2, u_2)$ and $v = u_2, -u_1, 0)$, how to we choose w?

Comment: @Eirik If those $u, v$ are orthonormal then $u_2 = 0$, which forces $u = \pm 1$. If you meant $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$, this forces $u_3 = 0$. In either case, we get $w = u \times v = (0, 0 , -1)$.

Comment: "Etc." means "Let $w=u\times v$." So long as $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal, their cross product will be orthogonal to both of them. And so long as $u$ and $v$ are in addition unit vectors, their cross product will be a unit vector.

Comment: @Travis, I meant $u=(u_1, u_2, u_3)$. But if $u_3=0$ I dont see how you can obtain the rotation matrix in the link I posted. Here,  $R$ consists of all the coordinates $u_1, u_2, u_3$ which corresponds to  $u_x, u_y, u_z$. This is the matrix that I am supposed to get to multiply the matrices $ASA^T$ as mentioned above. Then The matrix A has to contain all the parameters $u_1, u_2, u_3$, since the matrix S just contains cosines and sines.

Comment: I want a matrix $A= (\vec v, \vec w, \vec u)$ which satisfies the that the vectors are orthonormal and $u=v \times w$ and $ASA^T$ is equal to the matrix in the link I posted. If you just can give tell how this matrix A looks like.

Comment: I've given you a recipe for constructing $v$ and $w$, so I've given you a recipe for constructing a matrix $A$. Have you checked to see whether this recipe gives $A$ such that $ASA^t$ is the matrix in the link?

Comment: Yes, well I've tried $u=(u_1, u_2, 0)$, $v= (u_2, -u_1, 0)$ and $w=(0,0,-1)$ as @Travis said, and I got the matrix as in the link if you disregard the last coordinate $u_z$ in the matrix. (taking $u_z=0$).But why is it that taking u to be $u=(u_1, u_2, u_3) $forces $u_3 = 0$?

Comment: If your $u$, $v$ have length $1$, then $u_1^2 + u_2^2 + u_3^2 = 1 = u_1^2 + u_2^2$, so $u_3 = 0$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course if we also choose v to be $v=(u_2, -u_1, 0)$. But is there a way to find a vector $u$ such that $u_1, u_2, u_2$ all are nonzero? I've tried to multiply the matrix by using $u= (u_1, u_2, u_3)$, $v=(u_2,-u_1,0)/\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}$ and took the crossproduct, which matrix led to an awful expression, that did not lead to the matrix I wanted.

Comment: @Travis, I have another question. If you have 3 orthonormal vectors, $u_1, u_2, u_3$, $v_1, v_2, v_3$, $w_1, w_2, w_3$ such that $u= v \times w$ can it be true that $v_i v_j + w_i w_j= - u_i u_j$? If so, how come? I am working with some product of vectors and I get that this must be true?

Comment: @Eirik That's an interesting observation. Perhaps you should post it as its own question? If I see it tomorrow and no one else has written up an answer, I'll write one for you.

Comment: As for your previous question, isn't $u$ given?

Comment: @Travis thanks, I would really appreciate it. In fact, I also get that $w_i ^2 + v_i ^2 = 1 - u_i ^2$.

Comment: @Eirik I didn't see whether you posted another question but both of your observations are consequences of the fact that if the columns of a matrix are orthonormal then so are the rows. If you link your other question here I'll write up a proper reply if no one else has.